# Memory Leak even though I'm freeing the calloc

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I'm making a C program where I have to keep track of repeat inputs from stdin. The program works correctly, but I'm having trouble with memory leaks even though I'm freeing the callocs.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   
    char **words = calloc(1000, sizeof(*words));
    for (int a = 0; a < 1000; ++a)
    {
        words[a] = malloc(50);
    }
    char *input = calloc(1000, sizeof(input));
    
    int count = 0;
    
    while (1)
    {       
        if (fgets(input, 100, stdin) == NULL)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            words[count] = strdup(input);
            count++;
        }
    }
    
    char *x;
    int ret, repeat = 1, z = 0;
    
    while (z < count - 1)
    {
        x = words[z];
        z++;
        ret = strcmp(x, words[z]);
        
        if (ret == 0)
        {
            repeat++;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d %s", repeat, words[z-1]);
            repeat = 1;
        }
        
    }
    printf("%d %s", repeat, words[z]);

    for (int a = 0; a < 1000; ++a)
    {
        free(words[a]);
    }
    free(input);
    
    
    return 0;

}
```

```
==2635409==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 8000 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7f349bdfbdc6 in calloc (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0x10ddc6)
    #1 0x55b986a362eb in main /common/home/jtg136/Desktop/Homework1/Unique4/uniq.c:8
    #2 0x7f349bb230b2 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)

Direct leak of 250 byte(s) in 5 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7f349bdfbbc8 in malloc (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0x10dbc8)
    #1 0x55b986a36317 in main /common/home/jtg136/Desktop/Homework1/Unique4/uniq.c:11
    #2 0x7f349bb230b2 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 8250 byte(s) leaked in 6 allocation(s).
```

I used to have the string arrays formatted like char *words[1000], but I had to change to calloc because the former would always result in a memory leak, but now it won't stop leaking even though I freed it. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: `words[a] = malloc(50);` that allocates memory. `words[count] = strdup(input);` that overwrites the previous allocation and loses the pointer. So the original `malloc` cannot be freed - memory leak! There is no need for the first `malloc` as `strdup` allocates new memory for you.

Comment: Where do you free `words`?

Comment: Every call you make to `malloc`, `calloc`, `strdup`, etc. needs to be matched with a corresponding call to `free`.  So, make a list.  You're not freeing `words` itself, and you're not freeing the old values of `words[a]` before replacing them with the result of `strdup`.

Comment: Removing the malloc[50] loop and putting free(words) fixed the problem! Strange because I swear I did free(words) before and it gave an error for some reason, but it works now. Thanks guys!

Comment: @Vearaa Quote: "Removing the malloc[50] loop and putting free(words) fixed the problem!" It probably fixed the memory leak but it leaves you with a "very strange" program.

Answer (score 0):

In comments it has already been pointed out that the memory leak is due to

1. `words` never being freed
2. `words[count] = strdup(input);` overwrites the memory allocated by `words[a] = malloc(50);`

Fixing that will solve the memory leak but it's also interresting to consider the whole program structure.

**Why use `strdup` ?**

`strdup` is not necessary as `fgets` can be used directly. In other words - why read the into `input` and then duplicate `input` into `words[count]` ? Just read directly inot `words[count]`.

So instead of this "complicated" loop.

```
while (1)
{       
    if (fgets(input, 100, stdin) == NULL)
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        words[count] = strdup(input);
        count++;
    }
}
```

you can simply do

```
while (count < 1000 && fgets(words[count], 50, stdin) != NULL)
{       
    count++;
}
```

It's much simpler and you don't need `strdup` (and don't need `input`).

So your program could be:

```
#define MAX_WORDS 1000
#define MAX_LEN 50

int main(void)
{   
    char **words = calloc(MAX_WORDS, sizeof(*words));
    for (int a = 0; a < MAX_WORDS; ++a)
    {
        words[a] = malloc(MAX_LEN);
    }
    
    int count = 0;
    
    while (count < MAX_WORDS && fgets(words[count], MAX_LEN, stdin) != NULL)
    {       
        count++;
    }

    ....
    ....


    for (int a = 0; a < MAX_WORDS; ++a)
    {
        free(words[a]);
    }
    free(words);
    
    return 0;
}
```